# How to make certain element of GridView transparent to show image underneath?

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, imageview

Hello there,
I'm kind of new to Android, and I'm working on a simple image gallery. I have photo that is turned into `Bitmap`, then I cut it into 9 square(or equal) elements. Afterwards, I'm placing it to a `GridView` using my version of `ImageAdapter`. At last I want to make an effect that this squares randomly become transparent(gradient like from visible to transparent) and reavel another image beneath them(So the process can be repeated infinitely). I want to make it `OnClick` later to change photo, but right now I can't figure out how to make certain elements of `GridView` transparent. I tried using `getChildAt(int index)` or `getItemAtPosition(int position)` but all I get was `NullPointerException`. Can anyone help me with this? I tried to use many code samples across the web but none of it make it possible.

My main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int screenX;
    private int screenY;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> chunkedImages;
    private GridView gv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        loadScreenXY();
        ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizza);
        this.chunkedImages = this.splitImage(view,9);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView);
        gv.setAdapter(new GridImageAdapter(this,this.chunkedImages));
        gv.setNumColumns(3);
    }

    private void loadScreenXY() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        this.screenX = size.x;
        this.screenY = size.y;
    }

    private ArrayList<Bitmap> splitImage(ImageView image, int chunkNumbers) {
        int rows,cols;
        int chunkHeight;
        int chunkWidth;
        ArrayList<Bitmap> chunkedImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunkNumbers);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(chunkNumbers);
        chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight()/rows;
        chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth()/cols;
        int yCoord = 0;
        for(int x=0; x<rows; x++){
            int xCoord = 0;
            for(int y=0; y<cols; y++){
                chunkedImages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
                xCoord += chunkWidth;
            }
            yCoord += chunkHeight;
        }
        return chunkedImages;
    }
```

And my Adapter:

```
public class GridImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bm;

        public GridImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> bm) {
            mContext = c;
            this.bm = bm;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return this.bm.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(this.bm.get(position).getWidth(),this.bm.get(position).getHeight()));
                imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageBitmap(this.bm.get(position));
            return imageView;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException? And at which point would you like to apply the (more or less) transparent color?

Comment: after trying to get element from `GridView` using `gv.getChildAt(0).setAlpha(0.6f);` or `Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)gv.getItemAtPosition(0);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAlpha(150);
        c.drawBitmap(bm,0,0,p);` < both throw NPE. About the second question - I want to apply it to all 9 pieces one by one randomly, gradient like from opaque to transparent, so they can show image behind them(I did not implemented it yet because I'm still dealing with changing transparency).

Comment: Do you want to apply the effect only once?